# Is it possible to use QSS styling to change the font color of part of a QMenu item?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qmenu

In some applications, the **File** > **Open Recent** submenu is styled such that the filename is shown in regular, enabled text, and following it the path for that filename is shown in the disabled text colour.

Is it possible to use QSS styling to change the font colour partway through the string for a QMenu item's `title` string?

Comment: Which platform? Does the native style allow for this?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to achieve this on OS X. I have certainly seen it in native OS X applications, but off the top of my head I can't currently remember which ones.